# Print multiple PHP Files whitout opening them

Tags: php, pdf, printing

I have a PHP system that have orders, and items related to orders,

So I want to print every item related to specific order, without open the file.

I'm using a SQL query to show the pages:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE order_id = ".$oid.";
```

to collect items from this order and for each one, I write

```
<a href="view.php?iid=<?php echo $theResult['id'];?>" target="_blank">
  Item <?php echo $theResult;?>
</a>
```

So the page `view.php` is a default that receive `item_id` in `$_GET` and build the page as I want.

There's no problem until here, BUT:

I want to print any result for `view.php`, for each item in order, without have to open and click to print everyone.

Comment: Please, explain this `I want to print any result for view.php, for each item in order, withou have to open and click to print everyone...` more detailed. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Your question is not clear, I tried to remove some of the obvious errors but it did not help much. Please review your question and give a better example, e.g. in which script do you execute the "fast" SQL query? What is `$theResult['id']`? You might know your application flow, but we don't. Make clear examples with your question(s) that work without knowing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on still using the single view file `view.php`, a bit of a hacky solution could look like this:

```
<?php
    foreach ($items as $iid) {
        $_GET["iid"] = $iid;
        require("view.php"); //This will print whatever the view.php page does
    }
?>
```

Here `$items` specifies an array full of the ID's from the database.
By setting `$_GET["iid"]` to the id which we'd get from our database (`$iid`) and then including `view.php`, you can *emulate* a call to the file (and hence we'd print the `view.php` page for every item in the database).

If this is not what you want, it'd be awesome with some more info so we can help you along the way.

Comment: Seems that is what he wanted, so +1

Comment: view.php obviously is not printing.php. Why not include printing.php instead? And if you can't answer that, please explain why do you suggest to include view.php then for printing?

Comment: @hakre He has at no point specified that there's a `printing.php` page, but rather linked to the `view.php` page in his `<a>` links (`view.php?iid=<?php echo $theResult['id'];?>`). It is, however, hard to understand what he wants, so I simply *assumed* some code that might help him along the way. I assumed he wanted the `view.php` page to be shown for all items in the database (hence `$items`), and this **would** do such. If you feel the code isn't helpful, you're more than welcome to vote it down.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Your "answer" is only dropping some code and not explaining anything. If you had so much thoughts with the answer, share them in the answer to highlight the problems. Highlighting problems often help in solving them.

Comment: @hakre I've added an explanation to my code. There's absolutely no reason to get hostile, and you could've asked me to add a description right away, as we're all here to help.